# Yii2 Rest api put method return Internal Server Error - Failed to update the object for unknown reason

Tags: php, rest, api, yii, yii2

I am creating an API in yii2, all methods are working fine beside of `put` method. I am getting data in `before_save` method but getting below error when it save.

> {   "name": "Internal Server Error",   "message": "Failed to update
>   the object for unknown reason.",   "code": 0,   "status": 500,
>   "type": "yii\web\ServerErrorHttpException" }

here is my controller file

ProductsController.php

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;


class ProductsController extends ActiveController {

    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Product';

    public function __construct($id, $module, $config = array()) {

        parent::__construct($id, $module, $config);
    }


    public function behaviors() {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }

}
```

Here is model file
Product.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii;

class Product extends ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName() {
        return '{{%o2o_products}}';
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['name'], 'required'],
        ];
    }
}
```

And this is my web.php

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '<alias:index|about|contact|login>' => 'site/<alias>',
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'products'],
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'orders'],

            ],
        ]
```

I tried with removing `rule` with on create and on update statements. but no success.

Let me know if you need any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue recently and the solution is data is not passing properly. Normally it should pass as a json.

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
class ProductsController extends ActiveController {

    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Product';

    public function __construct($id, $module, $config = array()) {

        parent::__construct($id, $module, $config);
    }

    public function behaviors() {
        return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
                    [
                        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                        'only' => ['index', 'view', 'create', 'update', 'search'],
                    //     'formats' => ['application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,],
                    ],
                    'verbs' => [
                        'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                        'actions' => [
                            'index' => ['get'],
                            'view' => ['get'],
                            'create' => ['post'],
                            'update' => ['PUT'],
                            'delete' => ['delete'],
                            'deleteall' => ['post'],
                            'search' => ['get']
                        ],
                    ]
        ]);
    }
```

Try with passing data in `json`

```
{
    "name": "product name"

}
```